# Kubernetes: Unable to hit Pod from Master

Tags: kubernetes

I have one Master and 2 Menions.

```
Master IP: 192.168.20.50
Menion1: 192.168.20.51
Menion2: 192.168.20.52
```

I am able to run replication containers and create Services in Master. I have a problem in accessing Application container by using Master IP.

I did port forwarding from master to menion with fallowing command.

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl port-forward nginx :80 &
[2] 2229
[root@master ~]# I1201 22:15:46.822396 2229 portforward.go:213] Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:43020 -> 80
I1201 22:15:46.822603 2229 portforward.go:213] Forwarding from [::1]:43020 -> 80
```

So when I hit with localhost I can access nginx but when I hit with Master IP I am getting connection refused.

```
[root@master ~]# curl http://localhost:43020
I1201 22:15:57.031858 2229 portforward.go:247] Handling connection for 43020

<title>Welcome to nginx!</title> <style> body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; } </style>
Welcome to nginx!
```

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.

```
[root@master ~]# curl http://192.168.1.49:43020
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.1.49:43020; Connection refused
```

Comment: Are you using an particular overlay network? And are your machines IP-forwardable?

Answer (score 0):

You forwarded the Pod traffic to port `80`, you should be able to reach the pod at

`192.168.1.49:80`

not

`192.168.1.49:43020`

Comment: Ya I tried 192.168.1.49:80. It is not working either. Thank you

Comment: i realoze this is not the IP of your node. Did you try the Node IP, not the Pod IP?

Comment: Node IP is working perfectly. Not sure why I am unable to hit Master when I do port farwording